# What motherboard can I use for Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: motherboard

I want to set up a Ubuntu 12.04 system for MRI analyses. I will need 12.04, because some of the analysis software is not properly working wit later Ubuntu versions.

Can anybody recommend me a motherboard which will support:

- CPU i7-6700K
- 32 GB RAM
- **Ubuntu 12.04**
- 2 x 2TB HDD

I found **Gigabyte GA-H170-HD3** but I'm not sure if it will support all positions from the list?

Comment: This may be too broad - I'm not entirely sure, so I'm not going to unilaterally close this, but you may need to add more details of what you want for this to be concisely answerable.

Comment: This is a very broad question. Is there something in the [certified hardware list](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/) that doesn't meet your requirements? Is there something specific you need this board to do other than support the processor you mentioned?

Comment: Thanks for your comments and sorry for being so broad... I need just any mainboard (or in general: any configuration) that works with Ubuntu 12.04 and a Core-i7 processor, 32 GB RAM and two 2TB hard drives. This is for a research project. Since I am not so familiar neither with Ubuntu nor with configuring the right computer, I just want to make sure everything will work (I was afraid that the latest hardware might not support an older Ubuntu). I had the experience in the past that Ubuntu 12.04 was not so perfectly working with some generic Fujitsu computer (ethernet problems then).

Comment: @togtogtog Will you overclock this machine (if no why CPU with K letter) ?

Comment: @ivaan No overclocking; and there is no specific need for that CPU, using an i7 brings the advantage that the analyses can work in parallel on 7 of the 8 cores...

Comment: @Ivaan While the K-line does allow overclocking, it is also quite a bit faster when banging away on all cores (4.0 GHz for the K vs. 3.4 GHz for the non-K). If you don't have an appropriately threaded workload, the difference in single-core Turbo performance is much smaller and means the K-line is probably not worth having if you're not going to overclock. Then again, the price difference isn't really all that much.

Comment: @T.J.L. Yes, you are right but the most important thing in this question was answer to which chipset should togtogtog choose. For overclocking Z170 is a must but if this setup won't be overclocked H110 (PCI Express 2.0) or B150 (PCI Express 3.0) will be enough.

Comment: Have you thought about using an existing computer with a container or a virtual machine (e.g. VirtualBox) for this?

Answer (score 1):

If this requirements which you listed are all what you need I would recommend:

### [MSI H110M Pro-VD](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/H110M-PRO-VD.html#hero-specification)

- [$56 on newegg.com](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813130897)
- support for i7 processors (LGA 1151)
- Intel® H110 Chipset
- M-ATX form factor
- up to 32 GB RAM support (2 slots, dual channel)
- USB 3.1 support

If you won't overclock it is all what you need and there is no need to spend more money for better chipset.

There are sometimes problems with compatibility for Ubuntu with:

- Intel GPU on Skylake CPU's - [solution](https://askubuntu.com/q/691216)
- Sound: Realtek® ALC887 (exactly with 5.1 and 7.1 support) - [solution](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2273289)
- Ethernet: Realtek RTL8111H Gigabit LAN - [solution](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1661489)